# How to update an array data in database using NodeJs Async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am new to NodeJs and I'm finding the Non Blocking and Asynchronous nature of JS extremely difficult to understand and handle,
I have a piece of code which is supposed to Iterate an array
and for every iteration, I'm supposed to make a DB update.

Can someone provide the correct implementation of Async library functions and help fix my code?

**Code example -**

```
function updateFunction(conn, requestBody, callback) {

    let arr = [];

    async.each(requestBody.arr, function(item, callback) {
        let sqlData = []
        let columns = "";

        if(item.columnData != null){
            sqlData.push(item.columnData);
            columns += "`columnName` = ?,";
        }

        if(columns != ''){
            columns = columns.substring(0,columns.length-1);

            let sqlQuery = 'UPDATE someTable SET '+columns
            +' WHERE id = "' + item.id + '"';

            conn.query(sqlQuery, sqlData, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err, false);
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            return callback(null, false);
        }
        columns = "";
        sqlData = [];
    },
    function(err, results) {
    //Code never reaches here, don't know why       
     if (err) {
            return callback(err, false);
        }
        else{
           return callback(null, true);
        }
    });
} // END
```

Comment: I would go with ES6 `async` and `await`, or I would prefer using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).. they are certainly easy and reliable

Comment: Can help with some code snippet? The conn.query part is becoming a nightmare in my code, not able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

During your database query call, on a successful query your callback is not called, therefore causing your code to never reach the final callback.

You will want to add another return statement after your `if (err) { return callback(err); }` to let async know your database query is finished.

And another thing, [according to the docs,](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) the async each method's final callback does not invoke with results in its callback.

> A callback which is called when all iteratee functions have finished, or an error occurs. Invoked with (err).

Therefore, it is not required for you to pass a value into the callback statement within your iteratee function.

Modify your code to do this and it will work.

```
conn.query(sqlQuery, sqlData, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }

    return callback(null);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will adding the callback in successful DB update break the loops or just iterate onto the next element of the array?

Comment: Actually neither. The each method does not loop like a typical forEach loop for arrays. If you would like your array to loop sequentially you should use eachSeries method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.query(sqlQuery, sqlData, async function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return  await callback(err, false);
                }
            })
```

Something like this.. so the function callback is `async` here and we gave `await` which actually waits until the return call is finished..